# Why is PHP Doctine's free() not working?

Tags: php, memory, orm, doctrine

This is one is for any of you Doctrine users out there.  I have a PHP CLI daemon process that checks a table every n seconds to find entries that haven't been processed.  It's basically a FIFO.  Anyways, I always exceed the memory allocated to PHP becuase Doctrine does not free it's resources.  To combat this problem it provides free for the query object.  I can't seem to make it work though.  Here's the code:

```
 22     print "You are using " . (memory_get_usage() / 1024). "\n";
 23     $query = Doctrine_Query::create()
 24                 ->from('SubmissionQueue s')
 25                 ->where('s.time_acted_on IS NULL')
 26                 ->orderby('s.time_queued')
 27                 ->limit(1)
 28                 ->execute();
 29     print $query[0]->time_queued . "\n";
 30     $query->free();
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: I am using 1.0.3

EDIT: I have tried all of the below suggestions.  I was very hopeful for `unset()` as I had it in there before I found `free()`.

Here is more of the code to possibly aid in any help.  Before you question the opening and closing of the connection it will be daemon process that spawns children and from I have experienced the connection has to be unique.

```
  1 <?php
  2
  3 require_once('/usr/local/lib/php/Doctrine/lib/Doctrine.php');
  4
  5 spl_autoload_register(array('Doctrine', 'autoload'));
  6
  7 $manager = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance();
  8 $manager->setAttribute('model_loading','conservative');
  9 Doctrine::loadModels('lib/model/master');
 10
 11 while(1){
 12     print "You are using " . intval(memory_get_usage() / 1024) . "\n";
 13     $manager->connection('********************************************','master');
 14     $query = Doctrine_Query::create()
 15                 ->from('SubmissionQueue s')
 16                 ->where('s.time_acted_on IS NULL')
 17                 ->orderby('s.time_queued')
 18                 ->limit(1)
 19                 ->execute();
 20     print "[" . $query[0]->time_queued . "]\n";
 21     $query->free();
 22     unset($query);
 23     $query = null;
 24     $manager->closeConnection(Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getConnection('master'));
 25     sleep(5);
 26 }
 27
```

Some sample output:

```
You are using 14949KB
[2008-11-17 13:59:00]
You are using 14978KB
[2008-11-17 13:59:00]
You are using 15007KB
[2008-11-17 13:59:00]
You are using 15035KB
[2008-11-17 13:59:00]
You are using 15064KB
[2008-11-17 13:59:00]
You are using 15093KB
[2008-11-17 13:59:00]
You are using 15121KB
[2008-11-17 13:59:00]
You are using 15150KB
[2008-11-17 13:59:00]
You are using 15179KB
[2008-11-17 13:59:00]
You are using 15207KB
[2008-11-17 13:59:00]
You are using 15236KB
[2008-11-17 13:59:00]
You are using 15265KB
[2008-11-17 13:59:00]
You are using 15293KB
[2008-11-17 13:59:00]
You are using 15322KB
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is, that `free()` does not remove the Doctrine objects from memory but just eliminates the circular references on those objects, making it possible for the garbage collector to cleanup those objects. Please see [23.6 Free Objects](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_0?chapter=improving-performance#free-objects) in the [Doctrine manual](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_0):

> As of version 5.2.5, PHP is not able
>   to garbage collect object graphs that
>   have circular references, e.g. Parent
>   has a reference to Child which has a
>   reference to Parent. Since many
>   doctrine model objects have such
>   relations, PHP will not free their
>   memory even when the objects go out of
>   scope.
>
> For most PHP applications, this
>   problem is of little consequence,
>   since PHP scripts tend to be
>   short-lived. Longer-lived scripts,
>   e.g. bulk data importers and
>   exporters, can run out of memory
>   unless you manually break the circular
>   reference chains. Doctrine provides a
>   free() function on Doctrine_Record,
>   Doctrine_Collection, and
>   Doctrine_Query which eliminates the
>   circular references on those objects,
>   freeing them up for garbage
>   collection.

The solution should be to `unset()` the `$query` object after using `free()`:

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->from('SubmissionQueue s')
            ->where('s.time_acted_on IS NULL')
            ->orderby('s.time_queued')
            ->limit(1);
$query->execute();
print $query[0]->time_queued . "\n";
$query->free();
unset($query); // perhaps $query = null; will also work
```

Comment: I was really hopeful for that one.  I had unset in before I even found out about free then I hastily deleted it.  Even with it back in it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Doctrine_Query also has a free() method, at the moment you are just calling free() on your Doctrine_Collection, eg, try:

```
 $query = Doctrine_Query::create()
             ->from('SubmissionQueue s')
             ->where('s.time_acted_on IS NULL')
             ->orderby('s.time_queued')
             ->limit(1);
 $results = $query->execute();
 print $results[0]->time_queued . "\n";

 $results->free();
 $query->free();
```

Answer (score 0):

No experience with Doctrine (just some interest as I discovered it this week-end...), so take or leave my guess... ^_^

I would try and separate the query creation from its execute part:

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->from('SubmissionQueue s')
            ->where('s.time_acted_on IS NULL')
            ->orderby('s.time_queued')
            ->limit(1);
$query->execute();
print $query[0]->time_queued . "\n";
$query->free();
```

Not sure what execute returns, but just in case, it is worth trying... Unless somebody has a more enlightened advice! :-P

Comment: I'm a complete n00b myself.  I had the same idea, but it worked no differently.

Answer (score 0):

Try $query->free(true);

(?)

Comment: Sorry, I probably should have outlined what I actually have tried already.  That was my first though, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might just going to use PDO for the back-end parts that really don't need the ORM anyways since there aren't that many queries.  I just really wanted to have a single way to interact with the DB across all my apps in this system.  Maybe I'll give some more thought.