# How to free memory from Doctrine?

Tags: php, doctrine

if I have an entity repository and invoke the findAll() method, how would I be able to free the memory afterwards?  I ran a small test using $entityManager->clear(), but it did not do the job.  Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Do you need all records? Can you filter results, so less objects are created. The problem with php sometimes is, that it won't let you free the memory until the process has ended.

You can try it with **unset()** if you need all records. But be aware the memory won't be free, I think the garbage collector of PHP has a problem with cycling references, doctrine I guess has such references to be powerful.

A similar question to yours with an example:
[Why is PHP Doctine's free() not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295662/why-is-php-doctines-free-not-working)

If it is a command line with mass iteration can you please try

```
$this->_em->detach($row[0]);
```

as described here: http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine2-batch-processing

Comment: thx for responding.  Can you elaborate on the part where you say, "The problem with php sometimes is, that it won't let you free the memory until the process has ended".  What would a process be defined as?  If it helps, I'm running php 5.3, which I think Doctrine is able to take advantage of and reduce the memory issues from cycling references.

Comment: garbage collection hasn't been working for cycling references before 5.3, I have different strategies they help anyways to reduce memory allocation and are faster. Docrine objects are heavy, if you can use dql style. For a http request process terminate with it's response and command line process ends like any other command on the console. Just added a possible solution for command line script.